# iOS Safari: audio only recording noise

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I'm developing an application that allows voice recording in the web browser. This is working fine on most browsers but I have some issues with iOS Safari.
Below you can find an extract of the code, it is not complete but it gives an idea of what's going on.

```
//Triggered when the user clicks on a button that start the recording
function startRecording() {
    //Create new audio context
    let audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
    //Hack polyfill media recorder to re-use the audioContex
    window.NewMediaRecorder.changeAudioContext(audioContext);

    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function (devices) {
        console.log('loaded audio devices');

        console.log(devices);

        devices = devices.filter((d) => d.kind === 'audioinput');
        console.log(devices);

        console.log('chosen device: ' + devices[0].deviceId);

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: {
                deviceId : {
                    exact : devices[0].deviceId
                }
            }
        }).then(function (stream) {
            console.log(stream);

            let recorder = new NewMediaRecorder(stream);
            recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', function (e) {
                document.getElementById('ctrlAudio').src = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
            });
            recorder.start();
            console.log('stop listening after 15 seconds');
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('15 seconds passed');
                console.log("Force stop listening");
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.stream.getTracks()[0].stop();
            }, 15000);
        });
    });
}
```

For the record, I'm using audio recorder polyfill (https://ai.github.io/audio-recorder-polyfill/) in order to achieve recording, as MediaRecorder is not yet available on Safari.

The recorder works fine on all navigators (this including OS X Safari), yet on iOS Safari it only records noice. If I set the volume of my speakers at maximal level I can hear myself speak, but it is from "very far away".

All the online dictaphones/recorders that I found have the same issue, they always recording noise. (Tested with an iPhone 5S, 5SE and X, all up to date).

I'm a bit desperate because I already did a lot of research, but I didn't find any solution for this issue.

As required, the AudioContext is created on a user event (in this case a touch on a button).

I even tried to change the gain of but that didn't help.
Trying to access the audio without setting a media device isn't helping.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
```